# Momentum in center of mass-frame out of knowledge kinetic energy in lab-frame

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum

Consider the product of the four-momentum of an incoming particle $P_{\pi}$, and that of a target particle $P_{p}$. Making use of the Lorentz invariance of the scalar product of 2 four-momenta, the product in the lab-frame $(L)$ of the target particle $p$ should be the same as the product in the center of mass - frame $(\text{com})$. (for which holds that $\vec{p}^{com}_{p}+ \vec{p}^{com}_{\pi}=0$)
$$P^{L}_{\pi}P^{L}_{p}=P^{\text{com}}_{\pi}P^{\text{com}}_{p}  $$

Now the solution of an exercise in my book makes use of the (handy) expression

$|\vec{p}^{\text{com}}_{\pi}|=\frac{M_{p}\sqrt{T^{L}_{\pi}(T^{L}_{\pi}+2M_{\pi})}}{\sqrt{(M_{p}+M_{\pi})^{2}+2T^{L}_{\pi} M_{p}}}$

for the momentum in the center of mass-frame ($T$ stands for the kinetic energy)

Question : I can't seem to find the derivation for this (handy) formula and also wonder whether it's valid for all cases or whether there's a hidden assumption in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your formula

> $$\displaystyle |\vec{p}^{\text{com}}_{\pi}|=\frac{M_{p}\sqrt{T^{L}_{\pi}(T^{L}_{\pi}+2M_{\pi})}}{\sqrt{(M_{p}+M_{\pi})^{2}+2T^{L}_{\pi} M_{p}}}$$

assumes that the target particle $P_p$ is initially at rest in the lab frame. 

This condition was used in @JEB 's answer.

Here's a **geometric interpretation** of the formula, followed by the more general formula.

*(I'll admit that it took me a while to realize this. I recall your question and the quick answer from when these were first posted. Upon its recent bump by Community, I thought about it again.)*

The strategy below can be used to geometrically interpret other similar formulas.

---

Your formula gives the **altitude (segment BC) of a triangle [representing conservation of total 4-momenta] in energy-momentum space** ,
 where the base (segment OZ) is the system's total momentum 4-vector (which I will write as $\tilde p + \tilde \pi$ [to declutter the formulas])
 
and one side (segment OB) is the target's 4-momentum $\tilde p$, which is (**by assumption**) initially at rest in the lab-frame $\hat L$. 

(The rapidities are shown. In addition, I marked that segment BC (spatial momentum in the COM-frame) is Minkowski-perpendicular to segment OZ (the worldline of the COM-frame).

[image: energy-momentum-collision-robphy]

Let's write your formula using **rapidities** (the Minkowski-angle $\theta$ between future timelike vectors, where $\beta=\tanh\theta$ and $\gamma=\cosh\theta$). This will reveal what the numerator and denominator represent.

With rapidities, the 4-momentum $\tilde \pi$ can be expressed in terms of

- rest mass $m_{\pi}=\pi =\sqrt{\tilde \pi \cdot \tilde \pi}$,
- energy $E_{\pi}=\pi\cosh\theta=\tilde\pi\cdot\hat t$ (in a general frame $\hat t$),
- momentum $p_{\pi}=\pi\sinh\theta = \tilde\pi\cdot\hat t_{\bot}$ , and
- kinetic energy $T_{\pi}=\pi (\cosh\theta -1)$

So, your formula

> $$\displaystyle |\vec{p}^{\text{com}}_{\pi}|=\frac{M_{p}\sqrt{T^{L}_{\pi}(T^{L}_{\pi}+2M_{\pi})}}{\sqrt{(M_{p}+M_{\pi})^{2}+2T^{L}_{\pi} M_{p}}}$$

becomes... (where I will manipulate the numerator and denominator separately)
\begin{align}
|\pi\sinh\theta^C| &= 
\frac{
p\sqrt{\pi(\cosh\theta^L-1) (\pi(\cosh\theta^L-1)+2\pi)}
}
{
\sqrt{
(p+\pi)^2+2\pi(\cosh\theta^L-1)p
}
}
\\
&=
\frac{
p\sqrt{\pi(\cosh\theta^L-1) \pi(\cosh\theta^L+1)}
}
{
\sqrt{
(p^2+\pi^2+2p\pi) + 2\pi\cosh\theta^L-2\pi p
}
}
\\
&=
\frac{
p\pi \sqrt{\sinh^2\theta^L}
}
{
\sqrt{
p^2+\pi^2+ 2\pi\cosh\theta^L
}
}
\end{align}
Since (**by assumption**) $\tilde p$ is at rest in the lab-frame $\hat L$, 

the rapidity-with-respect-to-the-lab $\theta^L$ is equal to the rapidity between the 4-momenta $\tilde \pi$ and $\tilde p$:
\begin{align}
|\pi\sinh\theta^C| 
&= 
\frac{
p\pi \sqrt{\sinh^2\theta_{between\ \pi\ and\ p}}
}
{
\sqrt{
p^2+\pi^2+ 2\pi\cosh\theta_{between\ \pi\ and\ p}
}
}
\\
&= 
\frac{
p\pi \sinh\theta_{between}
}
{
\sqrt{
(\tilde p + \tilde \pi)\cdot(\tilde p + \tilde \pi)
}
}
\\
&= 
\frac{
p\pi \sinh\theta_{between}
}
{
|\tilde p + \tilde \pi|
}
=
\frac{| \tilde p \times \tilde \pi |}{ | \tilde p + \tilde \pi | }
\\
&= 
\frac{
\mbox{area of parallelogram [or kite] with sides $\tilde p$ and $\tilde \pi$}
}
{
\mbox{diagonal of parallelogram [or kite] with sides $\tilde p$ and $\tilde \pi$}
}\\
&= 
\frac{
\mbox{2(area of triangle with sides $\tilde p$ and $\tilde \pi$)}
}
{
\mbox{base of triangle with sides $\tilde p$ and $\tilde \pi$}
}\\
&= 
(\mbox{altitude of triangle with sides $\tilde p$ and $\tilde \pi$ })
\end{align}

---

So, the **more general relation** is
$$\displaystyle |\vec{p}^{\text{com}}_{\pi}|=\frac{M_{p}\sqrt{T^{p}_{\pi}(T^{p}_{\pi}+2M_{\pi})}}{\sqrt{(M_{p}+M_{\pi})^{2}+2T^{p}_{\pi} M_{p}}}$$
which involves " the kinetic energy of $\tilde \pi$ **in the frame of $\tilde p$** ''.

If your target $\tilde p$ is not at rest in the lab-frame $\hat L$,
then you can substitute
$$\theta_{\pi p}=\theta_{\pi L} - \theta_{p L},$$
expand out using hyperbolic-trig-identities and translate into masses, energies, and momenta.
Then your expression will become more complicated, involving components of $\tilde p$ in the lab-frame.

---

If you take the calculation with rapidities a little further (and I'll make the $\pi$ explicit in $\theta_{\pi}^C$ and drop the magnitude on the left),
one gets **The Law of Sines in Minkowski-spacetime**:
\begin{align}
\pi \sinh\theta_\pi^C
&= 
\frac{
p\pi \sinh\theta_{between}
}
{
|\tilde p + \tilde \pi|
}\\
 \sinh\theta_\pi^C
&= 
\frac{
p \sinh\theta_{between}
}
{
|\tilde p + \tilde \pi|
}\\
\frac{\sinh\theta_\pi^C}{p}
&= 
\frac{
\sinh\theta_{between}
}
{
|\tilde p + \tilde \pi|
} = \frac{\sinh\theta_p^C}{\pi}
\end{align}
where $\theta_\pi^C$ is the Minkowski-angle opposite to $\tilde p$

and $\theta_{between}$ is the external Minkowski-angle at the vertex B opposite to $\tilde p + \tilde \pi$,

and, by symmetry, 
$\theta_p^C$ is the Minkowski-angle opposite to $\tilde \pi$.

*(We can't use the "internal angle" at B because that would be a Minkowski-angle
between a future-timelike and past-timelike vector. 
No arc of a hyperbola is cut by those vectors.
With some work, one might be able to define such a thing.)*

Answer (score 0):

You should just derive it. Start in the lab:

$$ s = p_{\pi}p_P = (m + T, {\bf p}_{\pi})(M, {\bf 0}) = (m+T)M$$

Here $s$ is the Mandelstam variable called the invariant mass squared, and as you pointed out: it is Lorentz invariant. Note the only variable here is the lab kinetic energy $T$. The two masses are fixed.

Now consider the center-of-moentum system. Here the only variable is ${\bf p}$, the beam/target momentum (of course I am making them collinear):

$$ s' =  p'_{\pi}p'_P = (E_{\pi}, {\bf p})(E_p, -{\bf p})=E_{\pi}E_p+p^2$$

$$ s' = \sqrt{m^2+p^2}\sqrt{M^2+p^2}+p^2$$

Noting $s=s'$:

$$\sqrt{m^2+p^2}\sqrt{M^2+p^2}+p^2 =  (m+T)M$$

Solve that for $|p|$, and you should get your formula.

Comment: Would a $\cdot$ (`\cdot`) to represent the scalar product make the notation here more explicit and readable?